# I have developed write Chinese in Anki. It is working in Anki but not working in Ankidroid

Tags: javascript, html, css, anki

It is working on AnkiDesktop but due to character encoding It is not working in Ankidroid. I have tried many solutions but It is failed to load.
In Anki Desktop character length is correct but in Ankidroid same character length is incorrect.
Ex:- '比如'
In Anki Desktop Length is 2,
In Ankidroid Length is 7

So may be there is error due to character encoding. 
[GitHub link to code](https://github.com/infinyte7/Anki-maobi/blob/master/README.md)

[Image](https://github.com/infinyte7/Anki-maobi/blob/master/1.png)

Comment: Interesting issue. What would you like to happen / what is your question?

Comment: Issue it that, characters is not encoded in webview of Ankidroid. When I print length in Ankidroid it shows incorrect length for 2 letter word. It shows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have implemented it using existing js library HanziWriter.
https://github.com/infinyte7/Anki-xiehanzi